# 502 Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond

Tags: http, nginx, ruby, gitlab

I am new to gitlab and I am trying to re run an up an old git server which was down for few weeks. It was working a month back, but suddenly it stopped working. I have also tried to upgrade the GitLab. But still error is same.

Output for # gitlab-ctl tail is as follows

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2019-06-26_08:56:26.40033 10.5.11.118 @ - - [2019-06-26 10:56:26.366423831 +0200 CEST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 2422 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36" 0.033868
2019-06-26_08:56:26.45517 2019/06/26 10:56:26 Send static file "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/favicon.ico" ("") for GET "/favicon.ico"
2019-06-26_08:56:26.47561 10.5.11.118 @ - - [2019-06-26 10:56:26.454851912 +0200 CEST] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5430 "http://10.5.11.118/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36" 0.020684
2019-06-26_09:17:01.51633 2019/06/26 11:17:01 error: GET "/": badgateway: failed after 0.000s: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: connection refused
2019-06-26_09:17:01.51647 2019/06/26 11:17:01 ErrorPage: serving predefined error page: 502
2019-06-26_09:17:01.51648 10.5.11.118 @ - - [2019-06-26 11:17:01.515397035 +0200 CEST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 2422 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36" 0.000799
2019-06-26_09:24:39.79408 2019/06/26 11:24:39 Starting gitlab-workhorse v0.8.5-20161031.150348
2019-06-26_09:40:51.86440 2019/06/26 11:40:51 error: GET "/": badgateway: failed after 0.000s: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: connection refused
2019-06-26_09:40:51.86446 2019/06/26 11:40:51 ErrorPage: serving predefined error page: 502
2019-06-26_09:40:51.86459 10.5.11.118 @ - - [2019-06-26 11:40:51.862764251 +0200 CEST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 2422 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36" 0.001769

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
2019-06-26_09:48:30.83101 master failed to start, check stderr log for details
2019-06-26_09:48:31.83785 failed to start a new unicorn master
2019-06-26_09:48:31.85436 starting new unicorn master

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
I, [2019-06-26T11:48:32.609507 #10462]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
```

I really do not know how to solve this issue. Please can someone help me.

Thanks you in advance.